# Space complexity of recursion using queue as parameter

Tags: recursion, queue, space-complexity

space complexity = depth * memory consumed.
I have depth log(n) so in space complexity is O(NlogN). In one medium blog it says O(N). Therefore which is right?

```
class Solution {
public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
    Queue<TreeNode> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
          depth(root,nodes);
    while(nodes.size()>1){
       TreeNode  node1= nodes.remove();
       TreeNode node2= nodes.element();
        if(node2.val<=node1.val){
            return false;
        }
        
    }
        
        
        
        return true;
}
private void depth(TreeNode root,Queue<TreeNode> nodes){
    if(root==null){
        return;
    }
    depth(root.left,nodes);
    nodes.add(root);
    depth(root.right,nodes);
}
```

}

Comment: It is O(N), you have n nodes, and save all of them into the LinkedList, so it takes N space. And when the tree grows, your LinkedList grows linearly.

Comment: It is O(N) because queue is pass by reference, so it does not save queue on stack for each recursion. Thanks